# CSS transforms VS transitions

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

What are the key differences between CSS transformations and transitions?

Both of those are used to change the current shape/state of an object. (you can do pretty animations with JS etc..)

But it's still not clear to me which one to use where and for what.

Comment: Well, what are you trying to accomplish? They really are not similar, it's not clear what's confusing you.

Comment: Transi"tion" = Anima"tion" and transform = "NO" animation involved

Answer (score 29, accepted):

They're completely different things.

[Transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/):

> CSS Transitions allows property changes in CSS values to occur smoothly over a specified duration.

[Transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/):

> CSS transforms allows elements styled with CSS to be transformed in two-dimensional or three-dimensional space.

Comment: Are there any performance benefits in using transform over transitions in terms of the mechanism each uses for tendering?

Comment: transform and transition do different things -- they can't replace one another, so it doesn't necessarily make sense to compare their performance.

Comment: They are different but they both can be used to accomplish the same thing for moving elements across a 2d plane.  However, there are performance differences between the two: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Comment: Note that the Paul Irish article is outdated. In 2020 using a current generation business laptop, animations using transition top/left is noticeably smoother than transform translate() in the latest stable version of Chrome (80.0.3987.122 as of this writing). YMMV.

Answer (score 77):

### `transition` and `transform` are separate CSS properties, but you can supply `transform` to `transition` to "animate" a transformation.

---

### `transition`

The CSS `transition` property listens for changes to specified properties 
(background-color, width, height, etc.) over time.

**`transition` Property Syntax:**

```
selector {
    transtion: [property-name] [duration] [timing-function] [delay]
}
```

For example, the below styles will change the color of a div's background to orange over a period of 1 second upon hover.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: background-color 1s;
  /* timing function and delay not specified */
}
div:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

### `transform`

The CSS `transform` property rotates/scales/skews an element over the X,Y, or Z axes. Its behavior does not relate to `transition`. Simply put, on page load, the element will just appear rotated/skewed/scaled.

Now if you wanted the rotating/skewing/scaling to happen, say when a user hovered over the element, you would need to "transition" the "transformation".

Here's how: since the `transition` property's functionality is to listen to changes in other css properties, you can actually supply `transform` as an argument to `transition` and "animate" the transformation based on desired trigger (for example, a hover action).

**`transform` Property Syntax**

```
select {
    transform: [rotate] [skew] [scale] [translate] [perspective]
}
```

For example, the below styles will rotate a div over a period of 1 second upon hover.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: transform 1s;
  /* timing function and delay not specified */
}
div:hover {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: perfect one-line explanations!

Comment: transformation can also have transition effect. What I mean is something like: `transition: transformation 1s linear;`

Comment: The best answer IMO.